# Use CLT to find the probability

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

> $X$ is a discrete random variable with the following density function:
>   $$
>     f_X(n)
>   = \begin{cases}
>         c e^{-2} \, \frac{2^n}{n!}
>       & n \geq 0, \\
>         c 3^n
>       & n < 0.
>     \end{cases}
> $$
>   Define the variables $V$ as follows:
>   $$
>     V
>   = \begin{cases}
>         0
>       & X < 0 \\
>         X
>       & X \geq 0.
>     \end{cases}
> $$
>   Let $V_1, V_2, V_3, \dotsc$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables each having the same distribution as $V$.
>
> Use the central limit theorem to approximately find $P(20 < \sum_{i=1}^{20} V_i < 30)$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T4td.png).)

Not a homework. The entire problem could be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885578/find-the-expected-value-of-the-sum-of-random-variables. But it is not that relevant.

---

My work: In order to use CLT we assume that the variable is normal and then find the mean and std of the random variable.

$\mathbb E[V]=\sum_{n\geq 0}nce^{-2}2^n/n!=2c$

But how to find the variance for the Normal r.v.?

$\mathbb E[V^2]=\sum_{n\geq 0}n^2ce^{-2}2^n/n!=6c$ (not sure if it correct)

So $\operatorname{Var}[V]=6c-4c^2$

Comment: No work at all? Then does not invite to help.

Comment: @drhab Plz wait a sec for my work

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings next time publish your question if it is completely ready to be published.

Comment: To find variance apply the rule $\mathsf{Var}V=\mathbb EV^2-(\mathbb EV)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your calculations (I think they are correct) you can find mean and variance of $\sum_{i=1}^{20}V_i$.

Denoting these by $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ to be found is: $$P(20<\sum_{i=1}^{20}V_i<30)=P\left(\frac{20-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{20}V_i-\mu}{\sigma}<20<\frac{30-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\approx P\left(\frac{20-\mu}{\sigma}<U<\frac{30-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$where $U$ has standard normal distribution.

Comment: $\mu$ is just $20\times E[V]$ and $\sigma^2$ is just $20\times Var[V]$ because they are independent?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.